# C++ upscale trajectory

Tags: c++, opencv, gps, scale, vtk

I'm working on a project where i parse some lat lon coordinates from a csv file into x and y to build a trajectory so i save them in a vector of 2d points. From that vector of 2d points I build a bezier curve and form a trajectory of type Affine3f. Thing is the differences between the points is really small, at the 5th or 6th decimal point and the resulting trajectory is very small, corect geometrically and correct trajectory but very small.

This is the trajectory with:
[maxed out zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AK85B.png).

Zoom out a little bit:
[the red point is the trajectory and on the left end of the 2d grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZ1Iv.png)

Does anyone know how to upscale the trajectory so that it can be visible? I'm using opencv and vtk for visualisation, to be more accurate the viz module.

Comment: multiply each coordinate in the vector by some factor, e.g. 1000?

Comment: In addition to the scaling that @Miki suggested, a translation in order to change the origin of the points could be useful, too

Comment: Yep this might do it, thanks guys.